# How to make alarm sound using vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, vue.js

I am using websocket using vuejs like below.
socket would run when it gets 'any' on realtime.
And it gets data from rest api
When data.get is true, I want to make a short alarm sound like 'dingdong'.
How can I make this using vuejs? Could you recommend some advice? Thank you so much for reading it.

```
socket.on("any", async order =>{
  const data = await axios.post('/', {order})
  if(data.get === true){
    return ... // <-- some alarm occurs like 'dingdong'
  }
  }
)
```

Comment: Vue is just javascript, so any solution in javascript should work in vue as well. Doing a quick google search on "play sounds using javascript" brings multiple results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can play any sound in vuejs like this:

Html:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click.prevent="playSound()">Play Sound</button> 
</div>
```

js / vue:

```
var data = { soundurl : 'http://soundbible.com/mp3/analog-watch-alarm_daniel-simion.mp3'} 
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: data,
  methods: {
    playSound () {
      var audio = new Audio(data.soundurl);
      audio.play();
    }
  }
});
```

Your sound obviously needs to be hosted online to achieve it that way.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a possibility to play audio in Vue, so that you can insert a specific ringtone of your choice (.mp3, .wav, ...).

But tbh personally I don't know how to code that.

HowlerJS may help you, if you want to read something more about that, seems to be easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with pure JS, without any other library.

```
var audioFile = new Audio('your_audio_file.wav');
audioFile.play();
```

Of course you can implement that in your own method to let this be accessible from somewhere else...